# while loop is not working with == operator

Tags: javascript, html

there are two different codes:

---

### **first code is**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript while</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = "";
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    text += "<br>num " + i;
    i++;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### **second code is**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript while</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = "";
var i = 0;
while (i == 10) {
    text += "<br>num " + i;
    i++;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

first code runs perfectly but second is not working (does not print anything), can you guys how is it possible?

Comment: Can you explain how is it *not working*? I believe the code works just fine. What do you expect to get from the second code?

Comment: Because the value of `i` is 0 and the while loop condition is false `i==10` when the code execute for the first time. And thus the while loop is dead.

Comment: Can you explain how is it not working? in second code you have changed condition and with that condition output seems to be correct

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you mention that, maybe we can work toward a solution rather than only highlight the mistakes in the code.

Comment: my second code is not wot so i find out the answer of this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second code 'fails' because `i` is equal to 0, not 10. Simple as that. The while loop will not execute a single iteration since it fails the first test, i.e. `i != 10`.

If you want it to loop *up to, and including* 10, change it to `<=` like so:

```
var text = "";
var i = 0;
while (i <= 10) {
    text += "<br>num " + i;
    i++;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

Edit:

Yes, you can use `==` as a loop condition, however generally it's not used when you're trying to increment a counter. An example of it being used would be like this:

```
var i = 0;
var condition_satisfied = false;
while (condition_satisfied == false) {
    i++;
    if (i >= 10) {
        condition_satisfied = true
    }
}
```

Comment: can i use == in while loop condition, if yes can you give me an small example

Comment: Hi, I added an example to my answer. Let me know if I need to explain further

Answer (score 0):

The second code does not run becuase of `while (i == 10) {` , it is testing if i is equal to 10(coerced) which is never true.

If i is initialized to 10 then it will run but only once

```js
var text = "";
var i = 10;
while (i == 10) {
  text += "<br>num " + i;
  i++;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript while</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code is correct and it will print

```
num 0
num 1
num 2
```

But in your second it will never come into your loop as your variable is set as "0".

Answer (score 0):

i think all of you are saying, while loop code is only runs when condition is true and when condition is false while loop is terminate, in the second code **i=0;** while loop check **i(means 0) == 10** is totally false finally while loop is end in first time.